# Feature Layer performance improvement

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, performance

I have create a application where we show world map using arcgis .Here user does lot of interaction with map he click on the map or we highlight map programmatically so i want to improve performance of map .

```
var WorldCountries = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("urlr");
                map.addLayer(WorldCountries);
         map.graphics.enableMouseEvents();
                 featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("url",{
                    mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
                     autoGeneralize :true,
                     outFields: ["*"]
                  });
```

As below code shows i am using feature layer in snap shot mode so most of graphics are loaded in the client side,so i dont want to hit server again.So suppose in world map if i want to highlight some country i can use below code  so i dont want hit serve again.

```
dojo.forEach(featureLayer.graphics,function(graphic){
                                 if(graphic.attributes.CNTRY_NAME!=''  && alertNBulletinList.contains(graphic.attributes.CNTRY_NAME)){
                                     graphic.setSymbol(alertOfficeSymbol);
                                     map.graphics.add(graphic);
                                 }
                        });




   I have two question now :
```

1) **is there a way i can cache loading of graphics , now suppose in landing page i load the map with all feature layer i go to other  page of my web application is there a way i can cache the loading of graphics since it is nothing but json object sent from server**

2) Can i make use of feature collection to laod all the json object if so how do i query for some graphics

Comment: I've suggested something here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69344/how-can-i-retrieve-the-features-in-a-layer-without-adding-it-to-a-map/69346#69346

Comment: Thanks Garima , but the solution that u have suggested i already what i am doing , I just want to know if i can load all the data through json

Comment: well, you can create a web service that will do the query on the cached table/database. Once you get those results back from server, you could use JSON to parse/serialize the result set. This might get you started: [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example). Django API could help you with serialization.

Comment: What i want to do is when creating featureLayer we point to a rest based end point which returns json internally now each time i refersh the page the map contacts feature layer end point , can this somehow cached or if i save the json returned by rest end point in a file and load it.